# What's the diff algorithm used by GitHub?

Tags: git, github, diff

Git supports four diff algorithms, Myers, Minimal, Patience, and Histogram. And Myers is used as the default algorithm.

What is the diffing algorithm used by GitHub in pull requests and supported by the commits API?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

GitHub uses the default algorithm, `myers`.  It can optionally be modified to ignore whitespace, but is not otherwise configurable.

This isn't a guarantee of compatibility; it's just what's used at this moment.

Comment: Thanks, would you be able to share your source? or experiments you ran to conclude this.

Comment: I work at GitHub and looked at the source code.  There's no settings anywhere to pick an algorithm other than the default, so the default is used.

Comment: Thanks. This helps a lot. Anyone knows if there a plan to make this configurable?

Comment: I'm not aware of any.  You could ask in [the discussions](https://github.com/community/community).